# Augmented reality - how to manipulate objects

Tags: usability, interaction-design, hci, augmented-reality

With the new iOS ARkit, I've been wondering a lot of things about the intuitive interaction with objects in Augmented reality.

For example, I think people are going to try to move objects touching them through the screen, some kind of drag and drop with the device as glass boundary.

But after some thoughts, I think the device can also be used as control, I mean, move the device and move the object in space (not touching it through the screen), and we could have a 3rd option (not my favorite) and it is to add sensible areas to control the object.

What do you think, or know about this topic?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should keep the touch interaction - to move the object itself; & move the mobile phone to change the views of the object. 
There are 2 different actions in 3D modelling:
change object & change view. I would say the screen (touch) makes the bridge between you and the object,  while the mobile phone itself kind of 'renders' the selected/desired view of the object.